# How to output name when id is entered

Tags: javascript

**HTML**

```
<input id="employee_id" onchange="fill_name(name[1],this.value);" type="text" name="employee_id[1]" />
<input id="name[1]" type="text" name="name[1]" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var EmpID = [];
var EmpID[7] = "John";
var EmpID[8] = "Dave";
var EmpID[9] = "Nik";

function fill_name(element_id, employee_id){
    document.getElementById(element_id).value = EmpID[employee_id];
}
```

But it's not working and it says:

```
ReferenceError: EmpID is not defined
```

Comment: don't surround it by quotes.

Comment: Surround what exactly?

Comment: Don't surround 'name[1]' in quotes in your onchange handler.

Comment: `element_id` in the call to `getElementById`

Comment: Just change to `document.getElementById(element_id).value = EmpID[employee_id];` (no quotes around the `element_id`, as Daniel said.

Comment: I took off the quote from both, element_id and name[1], still not working

Comment: Have you checked your console ... ?

Comment: yes, it says: ReferenceError: emp_id is not defined

Comment: Please check my answer. That's because you defined `EmpID`, and not `emp_id`. And you declared the elements in your array in a wrong way.

Comment: I know I just changed it. I think the issue is that the actual variable (emp_id) is outside the issue, how do I globalize it to be used inside the function too?

Comment: You really shouldn't have changed your question to incorporate suggestions from comments and answers. This whole discussion makes no sense now because the code in your question works, so future readers will look at this and wonder what the problem was and what the hell the solutions mean. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change to

```
document.getElementById(element_id).value = EmpID[employee_id];
```

(no quotes around the `element_id`, as Daniel said)

And that's not how you declare an array. Overall, here's how your code should be like:

```js
var EmpID = [];

EmpID[7] = "John";
EmpID[8] = "Dave";
EmpID[9] = "Nik";

function fill_name(element_id, employee_id) {  
    document.getElementById(element_id).value = EmpID[employee_id];
}
```

```html
<input id="employee_id" onchange="fill_name('name[1]',this.value);" type="text" name="employee_id[1]" />

<input id="name[1]" type="text" name="name[1]" />
```

You might also want to use `oninput` instead of `onchange`.

Here's a good piece of code, adding an event listener in the JavaScript part:

```js
var employees = [
  "John",
  "Jack",
  "Joe",
  "Ian",
  "George"
];

document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("input", function() {
  document.getElementById("output").value = employees[this.value];
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="number" placeholder="Try a number from 0 to 4" />

<input id="output" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your employees ID in an object and use `eventListeners` instead of inline function calls.

Demo here :

```js
var obj = {
 "EmpID[7]": "John",
 "EmpID[8]": "Dave",
 "EmpID[9]": "Nik"
}

var name_field = document.getElementById('name[1]');
var ID_field = document.getElementById('employee_id');
ID_field.addEventListener('keyup', fill_name, false);

function fill_name() {
  var request = ID_field.value.replace(/\[|\]/g, '');
  if (obj["EmpID["+request+"]"]) {
    name_field.value = obj["EmpID["+request+"]"];
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="employee_id" type="text" name="employee_id[1]" />

<input id="name[1]" type="text" name="name[1]" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a **key value pair** `id -> name`, you can use an **object** to store your data. Keep HTML and JavaScript **separate**. An **example** with the **keyup event**  could look like as follows:

```js
var data = {
  // ...
  7: "Gustav",
  8: "Korben",
  9: "Wolther"
  // ...
};

var id = document.getElementById("id"),
  emp = document.getElementById("name");


id.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  emp.value = data[this.value] || "No name with this id";
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="id">
<input type="text" id="name">
```